# Asking if a device exists in industry or how to build?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I need an electronic device. Can I define what I want and ask if any possibility to do one.

Comment: No. -----------

Comment: The help center is a great place to get you started on how to ask questions. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

No, such a question would be far too broad. You need to narrow things down to the point where you can ask a specific design question that can be answered succinctly.

Can you give a general description of the kind of device you're talking about here?

Comment: A remote controller. For example, there are 2 amplifiers. When I press a button, I should make the amplifiers open at the same time but the amplifiers are far away from each other like 200 meter, so LED's may not work. I don't know much about alternatives, I guess remote controllers for cars has a broad range... I should check that.. thanks

Comment: @UygarUçar you can try with relatively low frequency RF, like 400 MHz or anything in the ISM band

Answer (score 3):

Such question would be too broad for the EE.SE main board, likely.
[As Dave have already mentioned.]

Here's what you can do.  [You've got enough reputation to participate in chats.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat)  We've got plenty of knowledgeable folks who participate in chat.  So, pre-discuss your question in [our EE.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).  Clarify it, narrow it down.

*p.s.* Last but not least.  We appreciate that you're first checking this on meta.